# ROS Answers SE migration: Kinect and PCL

Tags: kinect, pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone

I am currently working on a project where I have a pile of cloth and kinect camera mounted above this pile looking down on it. The aim is then to find a grasping point using the kinect camera so a robot arm is able to grasp a piece of cloth. My initial idea was to use the depth information to find the deviation between different pixels, an area with high deviation will then correspond to a piece of cloth sticking out. A good example could be this [image](http://wwwdelivery.superstock.com/WI/223/4029/PreviewComp/SuperStock_4029R-202615.jpg) where the folds will give a high deviation and thus a good grasping point.
A thing I have noticed during my research is the widely use of pointclouds and the PCL library with the Kinect camera, and therefore I wonder about using the pointclouds to find the deviation. My problem is that I cant find a good indeep tutorial how to use the PCL library and I wonder if someone has some good links or explanation how to process pointcloids with the PCL library.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9643/kinect-and-pcl/) by [Aslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/163/aslund/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2011-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [tutorials](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/) should get you started. Look at the [openni](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni) stack how to get your kinect to publish pointclouds. Also notice that PCL has it's own mailing list on which you can post questions.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/163/aslund/) on 2011-04-05**:
Hey, thanks for your answer. I have previously looked at the tutorials  on the PCL homepage, but their look very concrete and specific in my eyes and I had hoped there was some more basic guides that more focuses on the fundamentals and maybe short introduce the core methods in the library